Does the paper "W.F. Eberlein, Axiomatic charge conjugation, J. Math. Phys. (to appear)" exist?
I found the reference

Axiomatic charge conjugation, J. Math. Phys. (to appear)

in W. F. Eberlein, Models of space-time, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 71 (1965), 731-736, (pdf) however, I don't find the referenced paper anywhere. In 1965, Eberlein was working at the University of Rochester. Does anybody know anything about that paper?

Could not find any paper by W. F. Eberlin in J. Math. Phys. The best hope might be his archived material at UT Austin.

This paper has not been published, but the manuscript is available in the collection W. F. Eberlein Papers, 1936-1986 at Briscoe Center for American History. It is located in the box 87-1/2 (Research notes and drafts, 1949-1984). The title page looks like this:

